# how to take screenshot and not save it on gallery in android

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot, take

**I use below code for ScreenShot:**

```
 public class startActivity{  
    Bitmap layoutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mReLayout.getWidth(),  mReLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(layoutBitmap);
    mReLayout.draw(canvas);
    Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), layoutBitmap);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    mIntent.putExtra(Constant.BYTE_IMAGE, uri.toString());
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
private void setUpImageBitmap() {  
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constant.BYTE_IMAGE));
    String selectedImagePath = getPath(uri);
    mImageCube.setImageBitmap(Utils.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(selectedImagePath, 200, 200));

}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

**Class Utils**

```
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 2;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

How can I take a screenshot without saving it in the gallery?

Comment: what your question? you have to take screenshot but not save in storage? or take screenshot but not visible to gallery or Take screenshot but not getting in gallery? tell me

Comment: I do not want to store it in the galery. help me!

Comment: that means avoid to show in gallery? right?

Comment: Right !!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!! Can you help me!

Comment: yes wait search for that

Comment: Ok..................................

Comment: see my answer if any query then tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Below code for how to take screenshot for any android control, means ImageView or Layout. below code for ImageView.

```
  ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
  // View v1 = iv.getRootView(); //even this works
  // View v1 = findViewById(android.R.id.content); //this works too
  // but gives only content
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  myBitmap = v1.getDrawingCache();
  saveBitmap(myBitmap);
```

**saveBitmap(myBitmap);**

```
     public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
     String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     + File.separator + "Pictures/screenshot.png";
     String nomedia = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     + File.separator + "Pictures/.nomedia";
     File nomediaFile= new File(nomedia);
     if(!nomediaFile.exists()){
     nomediaFile.createNewFile();
       }
     File imagePath = new File(filePath);
     FileOutputStream fos;
     try {
             fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
             bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
             fos.flush();
             fos.close();
             sendMail(filePath);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
     } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
     }
   }
```

Now you dont want to show any images in gallery then you have to ceate `.nomedia` file in folder of screenshot save. see below code for that.

```
     String nomedia = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     + File.separator + "Pictures/.nomedia";
     File nomediaFile= new File(nomedia);
     if(!nomediaFile.exists()){
     nomediaFile.createNewFile();
       }
```

Above code already implemented in saveBitmap() method.  I think help you for you this...

Now you want to share this image then get path of image and share with below code.

```
   public void shareImage(String path) {
              Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
              Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
              shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
              shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
              shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
              shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
              }
```

Comment: just retrive images from your path and path convert in Uri. Uri set in imageview.

Comment: public void shareImage(String path) {. 
Where is it placed in my code?

Comment: this just for information to how can you share it. when you have to share images from you folder that time help you. you have to make one of code that in get all images from your folder now select one of image and share it. nothing. just google for that.

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-display-images-from-sd-card-tutorial/

Comment: What is the " String path ".

Answer (score 0):

The image files have to be stored somewhere. I think your actual question is how to hide image files from the gallery app.

To hide them from your gallery app there are two ways doing this:

**1. Create a .nomedia file:**

In the folder where you save your images (given by uri) you have to create a file with the name `.nomedia`.

**2. Prefix folder with a dot:**

You can rename the folder itself with a dot. Example: `.images`.